# "relay access denied" after changing domain A record

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

I'm experiencing issues with email, specificially "Relay Access Denied" errors after changing my `A record` for my apps domain name.  It was previously setup like:

- Host a

  - manages dns (mydomain.com in A record 123.456.789.122)
  - manages email
  - serves app

Now I have it so that:

- `Host a`

  - manages dns (mydomain.com in A record 99.999.999.999)
  - manages email (or at least I want it to)
- `Host b` (IP 99.999.999.999)

  - serves app

So all I did was go into my dns settings and changed the `A record` to Host b.  At this point my mail stopped working, yielding a "Relay Access Denied" to anyone that sends mail to foo@mydomain.com.  The MX record on `Host a` looks like:

```
mydomain.com. in MX 0 mydomain.com
```

I'm assuming that since I changed the A record for mydomain.com it's trying to manage email on `Host b`?  Do I need to modify my `MX Record` for the domain to point to an A record that is on `Host a`?  Sorry to be confusing, just want to have host a manage email, and host b just serve the site.  Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MX` record needs to point to a name that resolves to the correct host.

When handling your own mail, it's common to use a name dedicated this purpose which indicates the *role* and which can be updated separately from any other names in use, such as `mail.example.com`. If that approach does not strike your fancy I would suggest going with the canonical name of the host that handles mail, eg `zeus.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Ok, so I think I understand.  So you're suggesting that I setup an `A record` for "mail.mydomain.com" that points to the right ip (on host a).  Then set the mx record to point to mail.mydomain.com instead of just mydomain.com.  Is that all I'm missing here?  Again, thanks for your input!

Comment: Yes, that would work. Or alternatively setting the `MX` record to point to the canonical name of host a.

Comment: This solved my problem, email is flowing freely.  Thank you so much!